# Missing Proxy Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, proxy, doctrine

Everytime after clearing the cache of Symfony in the productive environment one Proxy is missing. Only one Proxy is missing and I don't know why. The development environment works fine.

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '.../app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__NestBiogasBundleEntityFermenter.php' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in .../vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 209
```

Symfony 2.5
Doctrine 2.2

**Config.yml:**

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
```

Do you have any Idea why?

Comment: I have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084299/if-clearing-the-prod-cache-get-error-of-doctrine-proxy