# If clearing the prod cache, get error of Doctrine Proxy

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

When to fold **PROD** cache on the **server** get the error Doctrine Proxy, while on the **local** host, all performed without error. Reset DEV cache on both hosts also successfully reset.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "v2.7.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "v2.5.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "v1.5.1",
    "twig/extensions": "v1.3.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "v2.3.1",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "v2.3.8",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "v2.7.1",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "v3.0.30",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "v3.0.10",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "v2.1.1",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "v2.0.0-alpha3",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.5.0",
    "gregwar/image-bundle": "v2.0.21",
    "sensio/buzz-bundle": "v1.0.0",
    "whiteoctober/breadcrumbs-bundle": "1.2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.3.3",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.3.2",
    "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "1.0.0",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "1.0.2",
    "iphp/filestore-bundle" : "v0.2.5",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "2.2.2",
    "oro/doctrine-extensions": "1.0.8",
    "devcookies/signgen": "^1.0",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4"
},
```

---

**My observations №1**

Run the console command for clearing **PROD** cache:

> sudo php app/console cache:clear -e prod

get error

> PHP Warning: 
>   require(/var/www/site.com/www/app/cache/pro_/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__AppMerchantBundleEntityProject.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/site.com/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
>   on line 209 PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/site.com/www/app/cache/pro_/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__AppMerchantBundleEntityProject.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/site.com/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
>   on line 209 [2016-01-29 10:30:55] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Compile Error:
>   require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/site.com/www/app/cache/pro_/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__AppMerchantBundleEntityProject.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   {"type":64,"file":"/var/www/site.com/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php","line":209,"level":6143,"stack":[]}
>   {"request_ip":"unavailable","client_ip":"unavailable"} PHP Fatal
>   error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message
>   'Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/site.com/www/app/cache/pro_/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__AppMerchantBundleEntityProject.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')' in
>   /var/www/site.com/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php:209
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}   thrown in /var/www/site.com/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
>
> on line 209

Run the console command for clearing **DEV** cache:

> sudo php app/console cache:clear -e dev

It's all right, and no errors

---

**My observations №2**

When in the configuration file, change the setting Doctrine

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    types:
        json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
    mapping_types:
        enum: string
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    ...
```

Changed config:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    types:
        json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
    mapping_types:
        enum: string
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    ...
```

**PROD cache is flushed without an error**

---

**My observations №3**

The recent amendments of code that actually all broken and added two related entities:

**Project** entity

```
<?php

namespace App\MerchantBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\CoreBundle\Entity\Cashbox;
use App\PaymentBundle\Entity\Cash\Template;
use App\MerchantBundle\Entity\Project\Terminal;

/**
 * Project
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="merchant_projects", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id_UNIQUE", columns={"id"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="secret_key_UNIQUE", columns={"secret_key"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="merchant_id_UNIQUE", columns={"merchant_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Project
{

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\App\MerchantBundle\Entity\Project\Domain", mappedBy="project")
     */
    private $domains;
    ...
```

And **Domain** entity

```
<?php

namespace App\MerchantBundle\Entity\Project;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Domain
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="merchant_project_domains")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Domain
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var \App\MerchantBundle\Entity\Project
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\App\MerchantBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="domains")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $project;
```

If you remove a connection Domain entity

```
    /**
     * @var \App\MerchantBundle\Entity\Project
     */
    private $project;
```

It's all right, and no errors

Answer (score 1):

Did you try force remove cache by

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
```

and then (of course db dump it will be nice)

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Answer (score 1):

**The cause was found.**

For dynamic conditions for route, I get a list of allowed domains from the database. To do this, I use **CompilerPassInterface**. And if there are entries in the table I am getting the error, and if the table to clear the cache was successfully cleared.

I expect that the data from the database tries to cache before the cache time to creators and project entities

[Screen of my CompilerPass class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsjgS.jpg)

Please tell me how to store the settings in the database and then use them in a mustache for route?

Comment: please ask a new question if you have a different issue. If this does't solve the issue, add it in your question. If it does mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You **clear** the cache on **DEV** enviroment which will also create the Doctrine proxies classes for you:

```
bin/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

However, while on **PROD** enviroment one have to **warm-up** the cache instead of cleaning it, which would translate in the following command:

```
bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
```

The other comments the other users made above regarding the `./var` permissions are obvious and common-sense, if you want your web server (Apache/Nginx/whatever) to be able to access the cached/logs files. So make sure you always run the below commands if you use to clean/warm-up the cache interactively in terminal (see the note below):

```
sudo chown -R <your-local-user>:<your-webserver-user> var/
sudo chmod -R 0770 var/
```

where:

- *<your-local-user>* is the owner of the files (like your Linux username)
- *<your-webserver-user>* is the usergroup that can access the files (eg. apache/httpd/www-data, whatever)

**Note**: if you are cleaning/warming-up the cache via a web
request/action - yes, it's possible! - then the above chown/chmod
should not be necessary since these folders/files will be created
using the running instance (webserver) owner:group.

Answer (score 0):

I found following sequence of commands to work:

```
chmod -R 777 ./app/cache 
rm -rf app/cache/*
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod  --no-warmup --no-debug
php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
chmod -R 777 ./app/cache
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities yourBundleName --no-backup
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Also if you use apache, you should set the correct owner to cache folder:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache app/cache
```

Comment: The problem is that I can not create the PROD cache

Comment: see my updated answer. you need to create the cache folder again

Comment: I execute all commands with elevated privileges via sudo, but the error

Comment: I noticed /app/cache/pro_/. Maybe there is a typo of pro_ instead of prod somewhere?

Comment: php app/console cache:clear --env=prod  --no-warmup --no-debug  
with error http://joxi.ru/RmzkB0JsWvn842